# What happens when a non-blocking v/s blocking code is called in doOnNext()

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor, flatmap

I want to understand what happens when we execute a blocking v/s non-blocking code within a doOnNext block

```
fun test1(): Mono<ResponseFromTest2> {
        return test2()
            .flatMap { responseFromTest2 ->
               // do some operation
               Mono.just(responseFromTest2) 
             }
            .doOnNext {
                publishMetrics(value1)
                publishMetrics(value2)
            }
    }
```

in the above function, the controller calls `test1` to eventually return some response. `test1` calls `test2`, performs some operation and returns the Mono emitted from `test2`. During this flow, I need to publish two metrics. I wanted to use `doOnNext` to publish the metrics and continue the flow with the Mono from the flatMap.

I wanted to know how to avoid blocking code when calling `publishMetrics()`. If `publishMetrics()` is a void function, would this be a blocking code and less efficient?
Would it be a better approach for `publishMetrics()` to return, for example, `Mono<Boolean>` to avoid blocking the thread. WRT to this, what's going to happen to the Mono emitted from `publishMetrics()` within `.doOnNext`? In general, what happens to the mono emitted by functions called within `.doOnNext`?

Comment: Being `void` doesn't change whether or not it is blocking. It may be easier to understand the notion of "nonblocking": This is a method which readies/starts the work in a separate thread/process/queue/etc, sometimes returning a handle with which to manage the eventual result/operation (e.g. Task, Future, Callable, Mono). A _blocking_ method, then, is just a plain-old-method you're used to: it doesn't do any fancy scheduling. In the case of simple methods (`foo() { return this.field + 2; }`) it's a non-issue, but if you're doing IO or cpu-bound tasks, then the blocking becomes more noticeable.

Comment: Do you have the option of using Kotlin [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) instead of Project Reactor?

Comment: @dnault No. Not allowed to use coroutines with this project